# loading for webpage until webpage has loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to have a loading sing in the webpage until all elements are loaded. I tried having popup alert using JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
      alert('loading');
   }
</script>
```

but did not look good, can I add images to alert window.

Or How can i have a webpage on the top that is displayed for few  seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a div, which should be on top of everything else on the page, with the loading text/images you´d like in it. Then you can hide it with JavaScript when the page loads completely.